# Загрузка образов Docker в kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Здравствуйте! Есть отдельный **Docker**, на нём создал контейнер и выгрузил в образ.
Этот образ на **ноде kubernetes** загрузил в локальный репозитарий **Docker** и деплою `(kubectl run)` в кубер.

Невыходит:

> Failed to pull image "library/myredmine:v1": rpc error: code = 2 desc = Error: image library/myredmine:v1 not found

Правильно ли я делаю ? Если да то почему не выходит, если нет то как правильно ? Благодарю.
В развитие темы - развернул приватный Docker Registry на отдельном хосте, с ноды Kubernetes docker`ом образы пуляца и пушаться ,

```
 curl -I http://10.0.2.254:5000/v2/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 2
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Mon, 04 Sep 2017 11:08:24 GMT
```

а вот при попытке создать pod кубер не может спулить образ

```
Failed to pull image "10.0.2.254:5000/redmine_cp:v2": rpc error: code = 2 desc = Error response from daemon: {"message":"Get https://10.0.2.254:5000/v1/_ping: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client"}
```

в интернетах предлагают перенести опцию --insecure-registry в файл 
  /etc/docker/daemon.json

не помогло (
я пока вижу 2 пути : или я чего-то не доделал или нужно учить регистер по ssl общаться, надеюсь на вашу подсказку ))
пс.куча благодарностей V.March за правку

Comment: Очевидно, куб пытается стянуть изображение и идет на hub.docker.com. В любом случае он не предполагает работу с локальным менеджментом демона и будет время от времени очищать локальные образы, поэтому не стоит пытаться так делать.

Comment: ну это действительно очевидно )) , я предполагаю что правильным путём будет развернуть локальный репозитарий для кубика, я верно думаю ?

Comment: Если только под репозиторием подразумевается registry

Comment: совершенно верно- registry , (новичёк и плаваю в терминологии ,)) простите)

Answer (score 2):

ответ - конкретно у меня была проблема в том что в кластере было 3 ноды (мастер и 2 воркера) --insecure-registry я прописывал на мастере и создавал под там-ж. Мастер передавал задачу создания пода воркеру, у которого эту опцию я не указывал.

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю вы залогинелись с ноды к реджестри и по этому можете свободно пулить.

Но так не будет работать с подами, так как кубернетис апи сервер ничего не знает о вашем реджестри. 
Необходимо в .yaml файл с которого создаете поды прописать сикрет с которого брать креденшелы к реджестри:

```
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: secret_name
```

Перед эти конечно же нужно создать его.
Все описано тут: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#specifying-imagepullsecrets-on-a-pod

Answer (score 0):

Нужно в `/etc/docker/daemon.json` на нодах прописать:

```
{"insecure-registries" : ["10.0.2.254:5000"]}
```

и перезапустить docker